# Error removing child div second time

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototypejs

I am using prototype 1.6.1 to insert and remove a div as a first child of another div.
So I have parent div 'A'

and I do

```
$('A').insert(divB,'top');
```

then later

```
$('B').remove();
```

This works fine, but if I create the same div a second time and then try to remove it again I get an error that `$('B').parentNode` is null. But if I look at `$('A').innerHTML` it does show the child div 'B' inserted. I am seeing this only on firefox (on IE8 works fine).

Any hints of why this behavior?

Comment: Are you inserting more than one "div B" into the document at any one time?  If so, that could be the problem - you can't have more than one element in the DOM with a particular "id" value. (Well, you *can*, but things won't work very well.)

Answer (score 0):

If Pointy's guess (multiple elements with the same ID in the document) wasn't correct, please post the example testcase (e.g. to http://www.jsfiddle.net/ or similar).